# Where does the plan for Griswold's Perfection drop?

Tags: diablo-iii

I found multiple ingredients for this item:

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/griswolds-perfection

Now I would like to know where the plans can drop. Is there a specified boss / location for this or is it just random anywhere as most of the stuff in the game? Plans do tend to drop from specific bosses though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Legendary equipment recipes are random, but the locations of materials can be found [here](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/83094-guide-legendary-crafting-materials-drop-locations).

I found mine on [Manglemaw](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Manglemaw) at Torment V (70).

Comment: fwiw reaper's wraps are not random, it only drops from the act 5 boss.  But I think that's the only plans that isn't random.

Answer (score 2):

I got mine in a cache after completing bounties.  Like every other legendary crafting pattern, it's 100% random (except for Reaper's Wraps).  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Its random, I got mine from a rift boss in act 1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Act 1, Cathedral lvl 2, in the bookshelf is the place to look.

Comment: How may times did you get the item there?

Comment: That is where the ingridients drop

Comment: @Assylum According to the comments on the post you linked, people are also finding the plans there with some luck.

Comment: I upvoted this because this is exactly where the plans dropped for me.